# Please retag MIME-type related tags on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

Please merge [mime-type] and [mimetypes].

Comment: Can we not close vote this, please? This is a legit request and needs a bit of attention.

Comment: Just a reminder, people: Please vote based on the merit of the question and not on your opinion of the user.

Comment: remember to vote on the new synonyms

Comment: @waffles: Does that mean they're *purposely* set to pending when a moderator creates a tag synonym?

Comment: @Bill Ill sort this out with the next synonym rev, I need to give moderators override powers

Answer (score 4):

Here are the tags involved:

[mime-type](/questions/tagged/mime-type) 186
[mimetypes](/questions/tagged/mimetypes) 17
[mimetype](/questions/tagged/mimetype) 4
[mime-types](/questions/tagged/mime-types) 3

I would suggest creating tag synonyms for these, after putting everything into `[mime-types]`.

A mod will have to do this, as we can't propose synonyms from a larger tag count to a smaller tag count.

Comment: Waiting for a second opinion before going ahead with the merge.

Comment: Never mind, looks like Bill the Lizard got it.

Comment: I'm just making the world a better place, one overlooked tag merge at a time.

Comment: @mmyers: Almost. Posting bug report... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58143/the-new-tag-synonym-proposal-system-isnt-bypassed-for-mods