# The new tag synonym proposal system isn't bypassed for mods

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-abilities, tag-synonyms

As an offshoot to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58140/please-retag-mime-type-related-tags-on-stackoverflow), it appears that the newly-introduced tag synonym proposal system is working a little *too* well (see the "pending" labels on the right side):

[image]

When a mod adds a tag synonym, it should be binding, instead of being put to a vote.

Comment: That is, unless he used the new GUI instead of the mod tools?

Comment: Nope, I used the mod tools.

Comment: Yerp I need to clean this mess up ... working on it today... will give mods override powers as well while at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working much better now, mods have the power to approve any synonym AND when using the mod screen it auto approves