# Provide a set of badges for people that create/vote on tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incentive for proposing and voting on tag Synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58512/incentive-for-proposing-and-voting-on-tag-synonyms)

Provide a set of badges for people that create/vote on  tag synonyms.

Comment: To help your cause, you may want to be a tad more specific, i.e., how many votes would you need to earn the badges?

Comment: Is this different from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58512/incentive-for-proposing-and-voting-on-tag-synonyms?