# Badge for voting tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, badge-request

I believe the [tag synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested) is not used as much as supposed. A suggestion stands there for months before it is accepted or declined.

What about drawing attention to it by giving a bronze badge for the first tag suggestion vote? 
Then of course a silver and golden could also be created.

I see [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58512/209901) was deferred in 2010. What about creating it now?

Comment: I don't even know how to navigate there. Maybe that should be more visible in GUI too.

Comment: Ah, I found it. Super-little link on the bottom of the tag page.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. This feature is so utterly ingored by everyone, nobody actually knows about synonym voting at all, let alone this neat synonym list.

Comment: Going there I don't even see the possibility to vote. I have 3768 rep on SO.

Comment: @JanDoggen as seen in for example http://stackoverflow.com/tags/shell/synonyms, "Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms", so it is likely that none of the tags in which you have +5 score have any suggested synonyms. This is not that strange: I have +5 in around 160 tags and I just see 16 suggestions. This confirms it is not a widely used tool.

Comment: I copy here @Andre Silva 's description when offering a bounty, since it will be lost as soon as it expires: _The SE voting system on tag synonyms has been criticized for not being the most effective as it could. Having just earned the "create tag synonyms" privilege I realized the system is not difficult to understand and I believe it has potential. A silver badge for voting on synonyms would benefit the site (silver badge (lexicographer?), voting up or down on 30 synonym suggestions)._

Comment: I think it's good to have a review for that ;).

Comment: @fedorqui, tks for having that text copied. Feel free to make it yours, if want to.

Comment: It is funny I got two upvotes today, maybe this was linked somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

As suggestion for adding a new review queue for tag synonyms:

In review there should be three buttons like:

- `[ Approve ]`

  > if you are agree with tag synonym suggestion.
- `[ Reject ]`

  > if you think this suggestion is not helpful or it is ambiguous or in a wrong way.
- `[ Skip ]`

  > if you don't feel there's anything to do with this suggestion.

Now after completing a new review user will give a Bronze badge and so on like other reviews.

---

I also suggest to add a page with a list of tags that a user can suggest over them ;).

Comment: Accepting a tag synonym is a sensitive matter with big implications. Having a review queue would make it easy to go through the queue and process the items there in a fast, random way. Thus, I don't think this is a good idea. I still think it is good to "reward" somehow the fact of reviewing the list, but in a way to improve the current situation, not making it unreliable.

Comment: @fedorqui Going to review for a user with a rep ~2.5K who are trusted in SE sites, I think this not making it unreliable ;).

Comment: This suggestion has merits, but I think I agree with fedorqui about it could have major implications. Firstly, I'd rather go with a smoother improvement, like just providing an incentive for people voting on synonyms the way the system is currently designed. Maybe your answer would get more visibility implemented as separate feature-request question.

Comment: [Give Tag synonyms their own review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202754/262755)

Comment: I really like this idea, but I feel like there needs to be something to battle against robo-reviewers, since it could be much more destructive in this queue. Maybe something like a large number of audits or a 30+ second waiting time.