# Reputation league pages should base the period reputation amount on actual votes, not the denormalized rep score

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-leagues, stackexchange.com

Alternate title: "How much reputation will you lose because of [deleted retag requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60227/please-stop-deleting-retag-requests)?"

[image]

I'm flattered to be #1 on this list, but clearly the "week reputation" is based on subtracting my actual reputation at the start of the week from my denormalized reputation, when it should use the actual reputation at the end of the week as the second value in that calculation.

<sub>(Aside: if you're curious, retag requests account for ~3200 of that 3803. I knew about the rest of it.)</sub>

Comment: I was wondering how my 25 rep brought me to the top of SU...

Comment: Yeah, random, really isn't that far up the list after the migratory patterns of SU-related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask a [friendly moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) to recalc your reputation on meta.stackoverflow.com (or whichever site has gotten out of whack) and it'll automatically be recalculated on stackexchange.com that night.

Comment: Well, I don't see the point of doing that, but if you're not going to change how the page works, then that's an okay answer, too. Thanks.

Comment: @Jon For better or for worse, reputation is a fuzzy number.  I can't see much point in fixing it on SE.com and *not* fixing it everywhere else, but doing so would be tricky and expensive.